# Android Performance Optimization Problem (Layout with JustifiedTextViews and CodeViews)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout

My problem is that **my application is quite slow** when I open an Activity full of JustifiedTextView and CodeView.

```
implementation 'com.github.softwee:codeview-android:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0'
```

I use these libraries in order to achieve justified texts and to be able to use syntax highlighter.

**Question A**: is it possible that these 3rd party libraries make my application slow? Sometimes 100-150 frames are skipped!

**Question B**: is it a good approach to do these things on my own? So implement text justification etc. on my own?

**Question C**: is it better to store strings in database (*SQLite*) rather than using *strings.xml*?

This is an example of an activity's exact source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".SortingMainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#858a9f"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="What is Bogo Sort?"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab" />

    <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
        android:id="@+id/bogoSortFirstParagraph"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#858a9f"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
        android:id="@+id/bogoDeterministic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#858a9f"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab" />

    <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
        android:id="@+id/bogoRandom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#858a9f"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab" />

    <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
        android:id="@+id/bogoEssence"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#858a9f"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#858a9f"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Implementation"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab" />

    <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
        android:id="@+id/bogoFisherYates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#858a9f"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab" />

    <io.github.kbiakov.codeview.CodeView
        android:id="@+id/shuffleCodeView"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#858a9f"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="@string/bogoTheory1"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab" />

    <io.github.kbiakov.codeview.CodeView
        android:id="@+id/swapCodeView"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#858a9f"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="@string/bogoTheory2"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab" />

    <io.github.kbiakov.codeview.CodeView
        android:id="@+id/isSortedCodeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#858a9f"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="@string/bogoTheory3"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab" />

    <io.github.kbiakov.codeview.CodeView
        android:id="@+id/sortCodeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without profiling, it's hard to know for sure, but a good first step might be to use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) to only render the parts that are onscreen, rather than having to lay out the entire thing with the `LinearLayout`/`ScrollView` setup that you currently have.

To know for sure, or as a next step after that, you should try taking a [method trace](https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/cpu-profiler?hl=en#method_traces) from Android Studio to see what's causing most of the work during the dropped frames.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Wow that tracer is awesome!